# Apple push notiifcations not working when sent from WebSite Root(but working from a subfolder within the site)

Tags: asp.net, apple-push-notifications

I am encountering a problem sending push notifications (using Moon APNS library) to Iphones from an ASP.net WebSite setup as an application in the root of my website that is hosted using DiscountAsp.

The problem is that when i try to send a notification from a sub folder(set as an application) the push notifications are sent successfully.

But if I try to send a push notification from the root of the website(using a copy of the files that are in the subfolder)
the notification is not sent.

The files in both the root of the website and the subfolders are the same.
This issue has me stumped.

Thanks in advance for any tips

Regards

Mathew

Comment: I'd say wrong categories, this isn't directly an iphone neither a apple-push-notifications issues but and ASP.net one

Answer (score 0):

Finally found what what was preventing push notifications from being sent from the website root.

An assembly version problem related to Newtonsoft.Json was throwing an exception in MoonAPNS.dll when trying to send the push notification to Iphones.

I enabled MoonAPNS logging(in my websites web.config file) and tried to send a push notification .

When I checked the Nlog file the assembly version exception was logged in that.

I added the following section in the web.config file

```
    <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

and I could successfully send a push notification.

The push notifications were being sent successfully from the site subfolders because the web.config file that was copied there had the required assembly redirect configuration.

Hope this is helpful to someone in a similar situation